# Installed compiz and now all my toolbars are white and without window decoration

Tags: kubuntu, compiz

I've installed Kubuntu 18.04 LTS twice with the same results. After installing compiz first all my toolbars disappear.

Then I go into *CCSM>preferences* and change the *Backend* drop down to *GSettings Configuration Backend*.
The toolbars reappear after I enable *GSettings Configuration Backend* and check the box for *Wobbly Windows* by default enables *Windows Decoration*.
After I've done that the toolbars return but are all white and without decoration.

I noticed that if I run this windows decoration command with `--replace`, I get this:

```
liveevil@liveevil-P5E3-Deluxe:~$ /usr/bin/gtk-window-decorator

** (gtk-window-decorator:32130): WARNING **: 08:35:56.021: Failed to load metacity theme 'Adwaita': Failed to find a valid file for theme 'Adwaita'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lq160.jpg)

Comment: isn't that mixing gtk and kde in a risky way?

Comment: Compiz is actually more stable than kwin. I still switch to compiz if kwin gets a little choppy...I've given up on doing anything else with compiz in favor of kde's desktop effects. Should I mark this as solved or close it somehow?

Comment: you can delete it I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to close this question because I discovered the built-in "desktop effects" in Kubuntu but not delete it because I did discover a new workaround to run compiz. By switching the "backend" in "preferences" from "Flat-file" to "GSettings" you'll regain your toolbars and have compiz working.

Comment: I might have needed also enabled windows decoration plugin/and or gtk-window-decorator --replace command, both with a pc logut and restart

Answer (score 0):

Question? Have you looked here yet?
https://kubuntu.org/news/plasma-5-12-5-bugfix-update-for-kubuntu-18-04-lts-testing-help-required/
Looks like there some bugs still, also note that if you have installed ccsm and "tweaked" your settings, that might be part of the problem as well.
Hope this helps. My own prefs are lightdm muffin nemo cinnamon, have had little diffifulty with all apps and software updates upgrades etc, seems to be stable and responsive from 16. - 18. on multiple linux versions, however the setup is a bit techish.
 Did some quick research and prehaps this would produce the desired results?
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-kde-plasma-desktop-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux#h3

Comment: Thank you for help. I tried what was proposed in the link but after I entered the last command it just came back to a prompt. Probably because I already have it installed. Good idea though, trying to reinstall the desktop.

Comment: I also tried Kubuntu 18.10 with no luck. =(